# Remove Root XML nodes from default output of Sql Server statement

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want @MyActualXMLOut to look like @MyDesiredXMLOut... How? Thanks in advance!

@MyDesiredXMLOut =

```
<MyRequiredRoot>
  <Property1>Value1</Property1>
  <Property2>Value2</Property2>
</MyRequiredRoot>
```

@MyActualXMLOut

```
<_x0040_MyTableVar>
  <MyXML>
    <MyRequiredRoot>
      <Property1>Value1</Property1>
      <Property2>Value2</Property2>
    </MyRequiredRoot>
  </MyXML>
</_x0040_MyTableVar>
```

The code below can be run as is...

```
DECLARE @MyDesiredXMLOut XML;
DECLARE @MyActualXMLOut XML;

SELECT @MyDesiredXMLOut =
   CONVERT( XML, 
   '<MyRequiredRoot><Property1>Value1</Property1>
      <Property2>Value2</Property2>
    </MyRequiredRoot>' );

DECLARE @MyTableVar table( ID int NOT NULL, MyXML XML NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar VALUES( 1, @MyDesiredXMLOut )

SELECT @MyActualXMLOut = 
    ( SELECT MyXML
      FROM   @MyTableVar
      WHERE  ID = 1
      FOR XML AUTO )

SELECT @MyDesiredXMLOut;

SELECT @MyActualXMLOut;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query('/')`

```
SELECT  @MyActualXMLOut = 
        (   SELECT  MyXML.query ('/') 
            FROM    @MyTableVar 
            WHERE   ID = 1
            FOR     XML PATH('')
        )
```

Comment: **Thanks! That's it!**

Comment: This works as an alternative to the solution I posted, just using `.query()` instead of `as '*'`

Comment: Jamie, @DanField, you are telling a value, which is already XML to be outputted as XML and then to use `query()` to get its XML... Why?

Answer (score 3):

`FOR XML AUTO` is trying to add information about your table name (which likely contains characters that aren't valid XML element names) and the column name it came from.

Change

```
SELECT @MyActualXMLOut = 
    ( SELECT MyXML
      FROM   @MyTableVar
      WHERE  ID = 1
      FOR XML AUTO )
```

to

```
SELECT @MyActualXMLOut = 
    ( SELECT MyXML as '*'
      FROM   @MyTableVar
      WHERE  ID = 1
      FOR XML PATH('') )
```

Explanation:  `as '*'` tells SQL Server that you just want the column value directly, don't use the column name as a tag name; `FOR XML PATH('')` says you don't want to add any additional root node around the output, just use as is.

Comment: Good way to do it also..  maybe less overhead

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is real life example, but:

The value in the table **is** the XML already...

Leave away the `FOR XML AUTO` (Anyway as pointed out one should prefer `PATH`):

```
SELECT @MyActualXMLOut = 
    ( SELECT MyXML
      FROM   @MyTableVar
      WHERE  ID = 1);
```

Or even simpler

```
SELECT @MyActualXMLOut = MyXML
FROM   @MyTableVar
WHERE  ID = 1;
```

Comment: So part of my assumption was that there could be some desire to generate this from multiple rows of the table variable - even though the actual case is fo rone.  If you only ever want a single row then this is sufficient and should make the most sense.

Comment: @DanField, OK, I see what you mean... The `WHERE ID=1` doesn't sound so actually, but you are right, that in this case one could create a multi-node XML from all XML values in the table...